# How to sort A-a-Z-z a list of names?

Tags: javascript, sorting, alphabetical

I need to sort a list of data by alphabetical order but in A-a-Z-z, were the name `Antony` comes before the name `antony` and `Zelda` comes before `zelda` so the list looks like this:

```
- Abigail
- Antony
- abigail
- antony
- Zelda
- zelda
```

The basic

```
list.sort(function (a, b) {
     if (a.name > b.name) return -1;
     if (a.name < b.name) return 1;
     return 0;
});
```

is producing a list like this:

- Abigail
- Antony
- Zelda
- abigail
- antony
- zelda

preferable language: Javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built-in for that:

```js
let list = ["abigail", "Antony", "Abigail", "antony", "Zelda", "zelda"];

list.sort((a, b) =>
  a.localeCompare(b, "en", { caseFirst: "upper" })
);

console.log(list);
```

EDIT: maybe you want this?

```js
let list = ["abigail", "Antony", "Abigail", "antony", "Zelda", "zelda"];

const compareUpperFirst = (a, b) => {
  if (a === "" && bb === "") return 0;
  if (a === "") return -1;
  if (b === "") return 1;
  let aa = a.charAt(0);
  let aal = aa.toLowerCase();
  let bb = b.charAt(0);
  let bbl = bb.toLowerCase();
  if (aal < bbl) return -1;
  if (aal > bbl) return 1;
  if (aa < bb) return -1;
  if (aa > bb) return 1;
  return compareUpperFirst(a.substr(1), b.substr(1));
};

list.sort(compareUpperFirst);

console.log(list);
```

Comment: How do you even remember stuff like this. Nice.

Comment: `toLowerCase` -> `toLocaleLowerCase` unless you are sure you don't have [non-English characters that could be problematic](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html)

Comment: @VLAZ: True; I was going for minimal adaptation of MIXT4PE's (now deleted) solution, without using the "fancy" methods (and OP's use case doesn't specify any, so even my `localeCompare` parameters are not very precise and `"en"` is a guess - should École go before or after ecole?) :P

Comment: With the following array it doesn't work very well, any ideas?

`["142019-newComp", "7 stuges","A company test", "A1QA", "AERGEGHFDGEQRG", "Business for Companies","aTestComp_D_CA_1418_21", "DEMO ALPHA 2019-04-15", "ATest comp 1","a12s","abigail", "Antony", "Abigail", "antony", "Zelda", "zelda"];`

Comment: And the second solution will place: `[A1QA,a1qa, ACorp]` whilst I'm looking if it is possible to place `[A1QA, ACorp, a1qa]`

Comment: any ideas ^^ @Amadan ?

Comment: You have to define the problem better than "doesn't work very well".

Comment: it produces results like this: `["A1QA", "a1qa", "A company test", "aTestComp_D_CA_1418_21"]`. So as you see its not exactly "A-a-B-b..."